# Create an oracle on a new chain

Tags: chainlink

If I deploy a contract like this one on a new chain:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e#code

Then I will still need some way to feed it data. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you deployed is a Chainlink Aggregator contract, you do not need to deploy Aggregator contract to get the token price data.

If you want to get some token price data in your contract, you should use AggregatorInterface in your contract and then fetch price data from the Aggregator contract deployed by Chainlink team. Instructions can be found [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/).